# Validate authors in google sheets using regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have an authors column and I would like to limit the input to a specific format using data validation and REGEXMATCH.

Let's say we have 3 authors (of course the validation should allow for 1 or more authors). In no particular order:

1. John Edward Smith
2. Jane Doe
3. José Luis-Visquez

The desired format is strictly this (including upper and lower case and punctuation):
**Smith JE, Doe J, Luis-Visquez J**

Anything else should throw an error.
No dot at the end

I tried this regex but it is matching incorrect inputs as well:

```
(?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\-?(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)?)\s[A-Z]{1,2}, )*(?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\-?(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)?)\s[A-Z]{1,2})
```

What is the correct regex that would allow for unlimited authors in this specific format in no particular order for the author names? The regex should be general to any name.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(B2:B4, "^\w+(?:-\w+)? [A-Z]{1,2}$"))
```

[image]

or more strict:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(B2:B4, "^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)? [A-Z]{1,2}$"))
```

Comment: Please take note that this answer works for single word last names only. Last names with more than one word (i.e. dela Cruz) are not counted. Also, "{1,2}" can be changed to "+" to take into account first names with more than 2 words.

Comment: Thank you @player0 but the input is going to be all three (or more) names combined in one cell separated by commas. I want to add Data Validation so that only this format is accepted